# Streaming via socket io with multiple servers from single source

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a single stream source S that produces ticker data.

I would like to integrate S into my node app that uses socket io. My app runs in a multiple server environment in production, let's say servers A and B.

Initially, I thought I would simply:

1. Use the socket io redis adapter: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis on both A and B.
2. Connect both A and B to S and simply have A and B handle the chunks of data emanating from S by simply broadcasting the chunks into the appropriate rooms.

However, after thinking about this, I am realizing that I will probably run into an issue where both A and B broadcast the same data to the client (and the client receives duplicates of the same information). Am I thinking about this correctly? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One client must be connected to one server, and the same connection remains open on the same server, it's called session stickyness, he will not have two connections open. In order to do that, you should use a proxy which will act as a load balancer on your pool of server, you can use nginx for example.

All you have to do is synchronise rooms across server to broadcast correctly to all users in a room (because some user will be in a room on server A and other on server B).

documentation about nginx and websockets: 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Hope it helps

Comment: I think you are forgetting about the redis adapter. It is my understanding that  using the adapter, broadcasting from one server will do a lookup on the connected redis instance and find ALL connected clients (event those that connected via server B) and then push data down to ALL them (thus my concern about duplication of data).

Comment: The redis adapter fixes the second paragraph of my answer. But if you are using the redis client you must broadcast through it, always and only through it. Obviously if you broadcast from your server and then broadcast again with the adapter, some of your client will get the same data twice. The communication with a single client can be done the same way as usual.

Comment: My issue is if all the servers are broadcasting the same data through the adapter, won't the clients receive the same data twice?

Comment: Both servers should not handle the same chunks, one server, one chunk an send that chunk through redis adapter. Or have a server that will not accept client connections but only receive the data and broadcast it to the redis adapter. Otherwise, you need to forget totally about the redis adapter and have each server handle its connections independently.